# How do I keep the backgrounds of my links the same height as my div background?

Tags: css

Here's what I'm trying to do. I currently have a vertical menu at the very tippy top of my web page. I structured it with this CSS code.

```
#main ul {
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#main li {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:50px;
}
#main a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    transition:0.5s;
    padding:30px;
}
#main a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:gray;
    background-color:white;
    padding:50px;
}
```

Bad thing is that when I get to the hover, I want the background to also change on top of the background that I've already set with my div. I can't seem to get it in the same height as my div while keeping the width at the place that it was at. What exactly do I have to do with my code to get it to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your HTML, too, so that we have a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS rule to make the `a` elements fill their parent elements:

```
#main a { 
  display: block;
  with: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No, I want to keep it inline so it stays vertical. Also, I want each and every single individual link to have it's own background working in conjunction with the padding and margins I specified in the code up above.

Comment: You didn't post any HTML, I assumed your `a` elements would  be *inside* the `li` elements. Are they not? If they are, the posted code should work fine.